# what is this error in android?

Tags: android

what is this error ??

```
02-17 22:00:54.199: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-17 22:00:54.199: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.dattsmoon.andFBChat/com.dattsmoon.andFBChat.andFBChat}: java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started.
02-17 22:00:54.199: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2496)
02-17 22:00:54.199: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2538)
02-17 22:00:54.199: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-17 22:00:54.199: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:958)
02-17 22:00:54.199: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-17 22:00:54.199: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-17 22:00:54.199: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
02-17 22:00:54.199: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-17 22:00:54.199: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-17 22:00:54.199: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-17 22:00:54.199: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-17 22:00:54.199: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-17 22:00:54.199: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started.
02-17 22:00:54.199: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338):     at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1227)
02-17 22:00:54.199: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338):     at com.dattsmoon.andFBChat.andFBChat.onActivityResult(andFBChat.java:190)
02-17 22:00:54.199: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3907)
02-17 22:00:54.199: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2492)
02-17 22:00:54.199: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338):     ... 11 more
02-17 22:03:14.428: ERROR/InputDispatcher(60): channel '40766410 com.dattsmoon.andFBChat/com.dattsmoon.andFBChat.andFBChat (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
02-17 22:03:14.438: ERROR/InputDispatcher(60): channel '40766410 com.dattsmoon.andFBChat/com.dattsmoon.andFBChat.andFBChat (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
02-17 22:03:15.298: ERROR/InputDispatcher(60): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=172, events=0x8
02-17 22:03:15.298: ERROR/InputDispatcher(60): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=163, events=0x8
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're calling `start()` twice on a Thread. In line 190 of your file andFBChat.java.

Comment: thanks alot, but tell me how you knew that from this error message ?

Comment: It's there in plain English: `Thread already started.`. And it happens as `com.dattsmoon.andFBChat.andFBChat.onActivityResult` is calling `java.lang.Thread.start`.

Comment: yes ,, Thread already started  ... i'm sorry i didn't see it :)